# SymPy: Extract the lower triangular part of a matrix

Tags: matrix, sympy

I am trying to extract the lower triangular part of a SymPy matrix. Since I could not find a `tril` method in SymPy, I defined:

```
def tril (M):
    m = M.copy()
    for row_index in range (m.rows):
        for col_index in range (row_index + 1, m.cols):
            m[row_index, col_index] = 0
    return (m)
```

It seems to work:

[image]

Is there a more elegant way to extract the lower triangular part of a SymPy matrix?

Is `.copy()` the recommended way to ensure the integrity of the original matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SymPy, `M.lower_triangular(k)` will give the lower triangular elements below the kth diagonal. The default is `k=0`.

Comment: I didn't know about it, either. When I need to hunt I usually use something like `[w for w in dir(Matrix) if 'lower' in w]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [99]: M
Out[99]: 
⎡a  b  c⎤
⎢       ⎥
⎢d  e  f⎥
⎢       ⎥
⎣g  h  i⎦
```

The other answer suggest using the `np.tril` function:

```
In [100]: np.tril(M)
Out[100]: 
array([[a, 0, 0],
       [d, e, 0],
       [g, h, i]], dtype=object)
```

That converts `M` into a `numpy` array - object dtype because of the symbols.  And the result is also a numpy array.

Your function returns a `sympy.Matrix`.

```
In [101]: def tril (M):
     ...:     m = M.copy()
     ...:     for row_index in range (m.rows):
     ...:         for col_index in range (row_index + 1, m.cols):
     ...:             m[row_index, col_index] = 0
     ...:     return (m)
     ...: 

In [102]: tril(M)
Out[102]: 
⎡a  0  0⎤
⎢       ⎥
⎢d  e  0⎥
⎢       ⎥
⎣g  h  i⎦
```

As a general rule mixing `sympy` and `numpy` leads to confusion, if not errors.  `numpy` is best for numeric work. It can handle non-numeric objects like `symbols`, but the math is hit-or-miss.

The `np.tri...` functions are built on the `np.tri` function:

```
In [114]: np.tri(3).astype(int)
Out[114]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

We can make a symbolic Matrix from this:

```
In [115]: m1 = Matrix(np.tri(3).astype(int))

In [116]: m1
Out[116]: 
⎡1  0  0⎤
⎢       ⎥
⎢1  1  0⎥
⎢       ⎥
⎣1  1  1⎦
```

and do element-wise multiplication:

```
In [117]: M.multiply_elementwise(m1)
Out[117]: 
⎡a  0  0⎤
⎢       ⎥
⎢d  e  0⎥
⎢       ⎥
⎣g  h  i⎦
```

`np.tri` works by comparing a column array with a row:

```
In [123]: np.arange(3)[:,None]>=np.arange(3)
Out[123]: 
array([[ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True,  True]])

In [124]: _.astype(int)
Out[124]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

Another answer suggests `lower_triangular`.  It's interesting to look at its code:

```
    def entry(i, j):
        return self[i, j] if i + k >= j else self.zero

    return self._new(self.rows, self.cols, entry)
```

It applies an `i>=j` test to each element.  `_new` must be iterating on the rows and columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use numpy function:

```
import numpy as np    
np.tril(M)
```

*of course, as noted below, you should convert back to `sympy.Matrix(np.tril(M))`. But it depends on what you're going to do next.

Comment: Wow; you can use a numeric package for symbolic computation!

Comment: Not really; Look at the resulting `array`.

Comment: This is certainly not the recommended way.  The minimum you should do, is convert it back to sympy: `sympy.Matrix(np.tril(M))`.